At least one field required in yup: Error: Cyclic dependency, node was:"reqNumber", js engine: hermes"
I'm creating an form with three fields. The first (driver) is required, so it's easy to do it with yup. But for the others 2 fields (fiscalNote & reqNumber) at least one of them should be required. Example: if "fiscalNote" is empty "reqNumber" should be required, and if "redNumber" is empty "fiscalNote" should be required.
I've tried a lot of things, but I'm getting every types of errors, like: "Error: Cyclic dependency, node was:"reqNumber", js engine: hermes".
I also tried add an Array with the fields name in the yup shape but I think the newest versions don't has supports. That is my code now:
import * as yup from "yup"
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup"

type FirstStepFields = {
    driver: string,
    fiscalNote?: string,
    reqNumber?: string
}

const firstStepFieldsSchema = yup.object().shape({
    driver: yup.string().required("Error message"),
    fiscalNote: yup.string().notRequired().when('reqNumber', {
        is: (reqNumber: string) => !reqNumber || reqNumber.length === 0,
        then: (schema) => schema.required("Error message")
    }),
    reqNumber: yup.string().notRequired().when('fiscalNote', {
        is: (fiscalNote: string) => !fiscalNote || fiscalNote.length === 0,
        then: (schema) => schema.required("Insira uma Nota Fiscal ou um N° de Requisição")
    }),
})

const { control, handleSubmit, formState: {errors} } = useForm<FirstStepFields>({
    resolver: yupResolver<FirstStepFields>(firstStepFieldsSchema)
})

yup version:
"yup": "^1.4.0",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.73.6",

